# Getting Error of Unhandled 'error' event events.js Angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, components, angular6

I am new to angular and trying to setup an existing project on the server. I have setup the project on the root of the server and moved my build to apache folder (/var/www/html). I have a carousel on the home page and getting errors of `main.da2430b946ec091e1c9e.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined`. I am using bootstrap carousel on home page.

When i run the command `node project.js` which have the `NPM PACKAGES` `API ROUTES` `ADMIN ROUTES` defined, i am getting error:

```
    events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1485:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sam/server/routes/chat.js:36:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sam/server/routes/api.js:26:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
```

I read somewhere that this error might be because of the port being used by other service. So i run below comands:

```
sudo lsof -i :80 # checks port 81
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2  886     sam    4u  IPv6  18050      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 2559 www-data    4u  IPv6  18050      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 2588 www-data    4u  IPv6  18050      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

sudo lsof -i :80 # checks port 80
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2  886     sam    4u  IPv6  18050      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 2559 www-data    4u  IPv6  18050      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 2588 www-data    4u  IPv6  18050      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

sudo lsof -i :8081 # checks port 80
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    8468 sam   10u  IPv6  54277      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)

sudo lsof -i :8081 # checks port 8081
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    8468 sam   10u  IPv6  54277      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)
```

Here is the Angular version details:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.14.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.9
```

Can anyone help me with this issue. I have spend many hours on it and didn't found any working solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hello, so from your app are other pages working? or server gives direct this error?

Comment: In my app there is home page and admin pages which open with http://siteurl/admin. Only home page is loading. Admin url is not working.